# Splitting of strings

Tags: c++

How do I separate the string into two , first one before ","or "." or " " etc and second one after that and then assign both of the to two different variables.
for example
`string s="154558,ABCDEF;         (This is to be inputted by the user )  string a = 154558;   //It should be spilt like this after conversion  string b =ABCDEF`

Comment: Research the joys of [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: You would need to find the index of separator, you can use find function and then use substr function to split the string.

Comment: See [std::basic_string::find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) for a way to locate the `','`, `'.'` or `' '`, and then you can use `substr`, etc... Or create a stringstream and as mentioned above use [std::basic_istream::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

Comment: you can try using this strtok(). 
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it can be something as simple as using rfind + substr

```
size_t pos = str.rfind('.') 
new_str = str.substr(0, pos);
```

Essentially what the code is doing is searching for the first '.' and then using substr to extract the substring.

Comment: Yep, that's a good way to approach it as well. You can use essentially any combination of the `find`, `find_first_of`, `find_first_not_of`, `rfind`, etc.. to step through a string with any combination of delimiters for the purpose of separating it. You can use your `new_str_b = str.substr(pos + 1);` to extract the second substring as well.

Answer (score 1):

The two primary ways to split the string on `','` would be (1) create a [std::basic_stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) from the string and then use [std::basic_istream::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) with the delimiter of `','` to separate the two strings, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main (void) {
    
    std::string s {"154558,ABCDEF"};
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string sub {};
    
    while (getline (ss, sub, ','))
        std::cout << sub << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_split_ss
154558
ABCDEF
```

Or the second and equally easy way would be to use  [std::basic_string::find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) and find the position of `','` within the string and then use the position with [std::basic_string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract the substring on either side of the comma, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (void) {
    
    std::string s {"154558,ABCDEF"};
    size_t pos = s.find_first_of (",");
    
    if (pos != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "first: " << s.substr(0, pos) << 
                    "\nsecond: " << s.substr(pos+1) << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_split_find_first_of
first: 154558
second: ABCDEF
```

Either way works fine. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.